# How context in the call() method works

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

For a series of exercises that are recreating Underscore.js, I am trying to understand how the call() method is working under the hood.

I do understand how the call() method works in the example below.

```html
let person = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    fullName: function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
let myObject = {
    firstName:"Mary",
    lastName: "Doe",
}
person.fullName.call(myObject);  // Will return "Mary Doe"
```

However, I am having a hard time to understand the idea of context as in `iteratee.call(context, collection[i], i, collection)`.

Here is the exercise I am working on:

```html
// _.each(collection, iteratee, [context])
// Iterates over a collection of elements (i.e. array or object),
// yielding each in turn to an iteratee function, that is called with three arguments:
// (element, index|key, collection;), and bound to the context if one is passed.
// Returns the collection for chaining.

_.each = function (collection, iteratee, context) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      iteratee.call(context, collection[i], i, collection);
    }
  } else if (collection !== null) {
    Object.entries(collection).map(([key, value]) => {
      iteratee.call(context, value, key, collection);
    });
  }

  return collection;
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many years ago it was common to use the word "context" to refer to the value that `this` should have during a function call. (It's not a good term and has fallen out of favor.) What that `_.each` definition is doing is accepting an optional parameter, `context`, and using that to set what `this` is when calling the `iteratee` function that was passed in so that `this` within the `iteratee` call is whatever `context` is. (If `context` isn't provided, it will be `undefined`, and `this` within `iteratee` will either be `undefined` [in strict mode] or the global object [in loose mode].)

For example, suppose you have an object with a method and you want to call that method for each entry in an array using `_.each`. You can do that like this:

```
const obj = {
    id: "some ID",
    method(value) {
        console.log(`this.id = ${this.id}, value = ${value}`);
    }
};
_.each([1, 2, 3], obj.method, obj);
```

Live Example:

```js
"use strict";

const _ = {};
_.each = function (collection, iteratee, context) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      iteratee.call(context, collection[i], i, collection);
    }
  } else if (collection !== null) {
    Object.entries(collection).map(([key, value]) => {
      iteratee.call(context, value, key, collection);
    });
  }

  return collection;
};


const obj = {
    id: "some ID",
    method(value) {
        console.log(`this.id = ${this.id}, value = ${value}`);
    }
};
_.each([1, 2, 3], obj.method, obj);
```

If you didn't provide `obj` as the third parameter, `this.id` in `obj.method` wouldn't work correctly because `this` wouldn't be `obj`, it would be either `undefined` (strict mode) or the global object. For instance (strict mode):

```js
"use strict";

const _ = {};
_.each = function (collection, iteratee, context) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      iteratee.call(context, collection[i], i, collection);
    }
  } else if (collection !== null) {
    Object.entries(collection).map(([key, value]) => {
      iteratee.call(context, value, key, collection);
    });
  }

  return collection;
};


const obj = {
    id: "some ID",
    method(value) {
        console.log(`this.id = ${this.id}, value = ${value}`);
    }
};
_.each([1, 2, 3], obj.method); // <== Note no third argument
```

The built-in array method `forEach` also has this parameter (called `thisArg`), as do many other built-in array methods.

But these days, it seems to me it's more common to just use a wrapper arrow function instead:

```
_.each([1, 2, 3], value => obj.method(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `this` as an implicit parameter of all functions. To illustrate, the following function will throw an error because there is no declared variable `banana`:

```js
function fruit() {
    console.log(banana);
}

fruit();
```

But the following function is fine because `this` is an implicitly declared parameter:

```js
'use strict';

function fruit() {
    console.log(this);
}

fruit();
```

You cannot pass `this` directly as an argument, because then you would have to redeclare the name:

```js
function broken(this) {
    console.log(this.name);
}

broken({name: 'Ann'});
```

The only valid ways to pass a `this` argument to a function are to either call it as a method, or use `call` or `apply`:

```js
// the following lines are equivalent
anObject.aMethod(argument1, argument2);
aMethod.call(anObject, argument1, argument2);
aMethod.apply(anObject, [argument1, argument2]);
```

In all cases, `aMethod` will see `anObject` as its `this` argument. However, the first case only works if `aMethod` is a property of `anObject`, while the others always work. The only difference between `call` and `apply` is that the latter takes all arguments after `this` in a single array.

Now to get to the line that confused you:

```js
iteratee.call(context, collection[i], i, collection)
```

`iteratee` is just any function, and `context` is just a variable that will be supplied as its implicit `this` argument. The `context` variable could have had any other name, such as `thisArg` or `object`.